# Logstash Technique For Multiple Field Names

Tags: logstash

Restating my original question. Hopefully this will be clearer.

I have a log message which looks like this:

```
13:26:24.160 Int 22000 COMPDBG: Interaction 065634563453 Some simple log text here    _I_I_04776_E0                          [07:3f] get data from cfglist(LIST_VendorCfg) item VendorRoutine, key L1Only result: 0\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04] ASSIGN: v_L1Only(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"0\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [07:3f] get data from cfglist(LIST_VendorCfg) item VendorRoutine, key Enabled result: 1\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04] ASSIGN: v_VendorEnabled(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"1\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04] ASSIGN: v_AgentGroups(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"DAT_IN_NCL_JDOE@.GA,VAG_IN_JDOE@.GA\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04] ASSIGN: v_VQ(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"VQ_SCT_VENDOR_END\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04] ASSIGN: v_Stat(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"StatTimeInReadyState\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04] ASSIGN: v_Priority(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"10\"
```

I can get everything I need out of it except for the ASSIGN values.

Given the message above, I'm trying to find a way to extract the six ASSIGN fields:-

ASSIGN: v_L1Only(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"0\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [07:3f] get data from cfglist(LIST_VendorCfg) item VendorRoutine, key Enabled result: 1\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04]

ASSIGN: v_VendorEnabled(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"1\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04]

ASSIGN: v_AgentGroups(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"DAT_IN_NCL_JDOE@.GA,VAG_IN_JDOE@.GA\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04]

ASSIGN: v_VQ(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"VQ_SCT_VENDOR_END\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04]

ASSIGN: v_Stat(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"StatTimeInReadyState\"\n    _I_I_04776_E0 [09:04]

ASSIGN: v_Priority(LOCAL) <- STRING: \"10\"

I've been trying the 'kv' filter with various 'value_split' and 'field_split' characters - but not getting anywhere fast.

Ideally I would like multiple assign fields each with its own value, but if the only way to do this is to allocate unique field names for each instance of ASSIGN then so be it.

Thanks.

Comment: it's not at all clear what you are asking/how your log is formatted.  Are the \n's in your log real new lines or are they literal \n's?  Are you asking to repeatedly match the same pattern against the input string and then have a single event that has all of the properties that match?  Ie in you above example, do you want an event that has `v_L1Only: 0...` or what?

Comment: I have re-written the question. Hopefully its clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your example is all one line (if not, look into the multi-line codec), and that you want to pull out the values prefaced by "ASSIGN", you're going to want to use the "kv" (key/value) filter.  You can give it a regexp that defines the separator.  Here's [the doc](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/kv).